# Vim - use vim with clipboard inside tmux on mac

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard, tmux

**Objective:** I want seamless integration between (1) tmux copy/paste buffer, (2) system clipboard, (3) Vim `"*` or `"+` registers.  I do not want Vim to default to clipboard integration on every yank and put; I want to explicitly invoke it with either of these registers.

**Status:** This works as expected when I run Vim outside of tmux.  Integration between tmux copy/paste and my clipboard also works fine (without `reattach-to-user-namespace`).  My only problem is when I am running Vim inside tmux and want to use these registers - in this case they behave entirely separately from either my system clipboard of tmux copy/paste buffer.

I don't think I should need `reattach-to-user-namespace` because already my tmux/clipboard integration works correctly outside of Vim.  I don't think I need `set clipboard=unnamed` because I want to use the default clipboard registers.  But I'm not entirely sure what I *do* need.

**Specs & Settings:** I am running OS X Sierra 10.12.3, tmux 2.3, and Vim 8 with `+clipboard`.  I am running this all in iTerm 2 (build 3.0.14), not using the iTerm-tmux integration, and with "Applications in terminal may access clipboard" enabled. Below are the settings I think might be relevant from my dotfiles.

`~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g focus-events on
bind-key v copy-mode
bind-key p paste-buffer
bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy Enter copy-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy r rectangle-toggle
```

`~/.vimrc`

```
Plugin 'tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
```

If there are other settings that may be relevant I'm happy to add to this list upon request.  I don't want to post my full `tmux.conf` and `vimrc` files because that would just be bloated.

**Not A Duplicate:** There are a lot of questions related to Vim/tmux clipboard integration in OS X, and I've read through them but I'm still having trouble.  I don't think this is a duplicate of those questions.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried using `reattach-to-user-namespace` and it worked perfectly.  I don't understand why Vim needed this but just regular copy/paste from tmux did not.

Comment: If I am wrong and I do need `reattach-to-user-namespace` I would like to know why I need it for this and don't need it when copying from tmux normally before accepting the answer.

Comment: How did you install tmux? How did you install Vim?

Comment: I think Homebrew?  I don't remember specifically but that's usually my first go-to approach.